# What does the localhost: 3000 server created by express mean?

Tags: node.js, express, web, server

What is it that you access when you type in "localhost: 3000" onto your browser? What does that represent?

Comment: Hi @jedi_1971 Mostly people on Stackoverflow ask question which are a little specific to some usecase or some problems. Your question is too generic and should be understood in more logical way. [Read here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)

Answer (score 0):

`localhost` is a special domain name that always refers to your local computer.

`3000` is a tcp port. When you open a url such as:

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

Then a connection will get opened to port 3000.

When you specify a url like:

```
http://localhost/
```

Then you will open port 80, because the default HTTP port is 80

Answer (score 0):

`localhost:3000` is a local development server running on port 3000 of your computer. It is created by the express and can render html pages and route the apis for different requests. With the expressjs framework you can create different routes and associate it with the development or production port. You can also change the port during the development which can be done by changing the value of listening port on your app/index/server .js file.